# why css tabs look different in ie and firefox

Tags: html, css

i have created some tabs using css but they look horrible in ie 7. Why?
Here is the html

```
<ul>
    <li><a href='view.php'>View</a><li>
    <li><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><li>
    <li><a href='www.google.com'>Search</a><li>
</ul>
```

and here is the css

```
ul{list-style:none;height:20px;}
li{background-color:#ff0;float:left;margin:5px;width:60px;text-align:center;display:block;}
li:hover{background-color:#009;}
a{text-decoration:none;}
```

Here is how it looks in ff

[image: appearance in ff]

Here is how it looks in ie
[image]

Comment: Looks OK in IE for me (See http://jsfiddle.net/evupX/)

Is there any other CSS or markup that you did not put in your example? (make sure you turn off compatibility view in IE8+) IE with compatibility view adds empty <li />  tags in between, why?

Comment: looks ok on jsfiddle but looks different in internet explorer. (see http://jsfiddle.net/KXbbg/)

Comment: Maybe try setting a width on the `ul` equal to the width of each `li` plus margins. From your screenshot though, it seems like you have more there because that really doesn't look like a 10px margin between each one...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not terminating your list items correctly. Try replacing each `<li>` at the end of the lines with `</li>` and you should be good.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a reset CSS like :

http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

It could be appreciable...

**Edit**

@Kaivosukeltaja is right :

```
<li>...</li>
```

Will fix your problem. But you can let the CSS reset on your page ;)